# RSYNC compare folder to tarfile

Tags: python, bash, rsync

I have googled a bit and it seems that you can not make an incremental backup of a folder when you compare it to the same folder in a tarformat.

I doubt that uncompressing the folder then rsycing it and recompressing the folder is a fast way to get the job done.

Do any of you have a workaround or alternative to rsync to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not use tar with -ru to recursively update your tar file?

Comment: Good idea, but by appending the files wont I have some files double? I only need to keep the newest version

Answer (score 1):

I am using cygwin on my Windows machine (at work) and cannot test the tar command, but I believe the file will be updated and you will NOT be left with two copies of the file.  I know the zip command works:

```
zip -ru dest/test.tar src
```

I cannot comment on performance of zip vs tar vs rsync.  If you have many many files this may become worth investigating.

Comment: I'll give it a go and will report back to you